# Dirac equation plane wave solutions for antiparticles (Peskin QFT book overlooked?)

Tags: field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation, spinors

I am puzzled by the derivation given here about the Dirac equation plane wave solutions of Peskin QFT book (shown in (3.59) and (3.62) on the scanned image below):
$$
(i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m) \psi=0 \tag{eq.0}
$$

1. For $\psi(x) =u(p) e^{-i p\cdot x}$, we get the equation of motion (eq.0) becomes
   $$
   (\gamma^0 E -\gamma^j p^j -m) u(p)  =0 \tag{eq.1}
   $$
   with $j=1,2,3.$ Here we  choose $p^0=E>0$.

Say I agree with the solution
$$
u(p)=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{ p \cdot \sigma} \zeta^s \\ \sqrt{ p \cdot \bar\sigma} \zeta^s \end{pmatrix} \tag{eq.1-sol}
$$
2. For $\psi(x) =v(p) e^{+i p\cdot x}$, we get the equation of motion (eq.0) becomes
$$
(-\gamma^0 E +\gamma^j p^j -m) v(p)  =0 \tag{eq.2}
$$
with $j=1,2,3$, here we still choose $p^0=E>0$

Naively, I can derive $v(p)$ by a mapping from the known solutions (eq.1-sol)? Naively, I thought that we just either map
$$
(E,p^j) \mapsto (-E,-p^j)
$$
then we plug in (eq.1-sol) to get a rewriting of eq.2
to
$
(+\gamma^0 E -\gamma^j p^j -m) v(-p)  =0 \tag{eq.2}
$
so we have also a change of $\zeta$ to $\eta$
$$
v(-p)=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{ p \cdot \sigma} \eta^s \\ \sqrt{ p \cdot \bar\sigma} \eta^s \end{pmatrix} \tag{eq.2-sol-a}
$$
or
$$
v( p)=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{ -p \cdot \sigma} \eta^s \\ \sqrt{ -p \cdot \bar\sigma} \eta^s \end{pmatrix} \tag{eq.2-sol-b}
$$
But these are all different from Peskin's
$$
v( p)=\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{  p \cdot \sigma} \eta^s \\ -\sqrt{  p \cdot \bar\sigma} \eta^s \end{pmatrix} \tag{eq.2-sol}
$$

> **Why do I get (eq.2-sol-a) or (eq.2-sol-b) instead of (eq.2-sol)?** Can you correct my mistakes?

---

[image]

Comment: A similar derivation can be found in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_spinor

Answer (score 1):

The way that Peskin and Schroeder (P&S) solves the Dirac equation is by going to the rest frame first. The first solution is then given by
$$ u(p_0)=\sqrt{m}\left(\begin{array}{c} \xi \\ \xi \end{array} \right) , $$
as given in (3.47) in P&S. The full solution then comes from a Lorentz boost of this solution.

When you do the same for the antiparticle solution, you'll get
$$ v(p_0)=\sqrt{m}\left(\begin{array}{c} \xi \\ -\xi \end{array} \right) . $$
So the minus sign in the lower entry does not have anything to do with the momentum vector or its direction. Note that these are positive energy solutions, so $E>0$ for both the particle and the antiparticle.

Comment: thanks. Then I have a question: suppose I boost my solution to such that among the 4 components, only 1 of them is nonzero (this is possible see Peskin book, depending on whether the you have spin up or down, left or right chirality),

Comment: then in that case, how do you tell which component is a particle or anti-particle just by staring at a component of $\xi$ in your notation?

Comment: Are your referring to the massless limit? In that case you have Weyl spinors, which are not the same thing as the particle and antiparticle solutions.